# Div text but exclude some tag text

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying get all text from a div but want to exclude some text in some tags. Like all text in `<header><h2>some text</h2><header>` and maybe also exclude text of a `<footer>`.

I already have something like:

```
tree = <some html> 
XpathArticleSummary = "string(div)"
divs = tree.xpath(XpathArticleSummary)
```

What i want is something like:

```
XpathArticleSummary = "string(div[not(header|footer)])"
```

But this of course doesn't work :)

Is there a way to exclude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using lxml this xpath should work:

```
div//text()[not(parent::footer or parent::header)]
```

it should gie you a list of text nodes.

Comment: Thnx, i replaced parent with ancestor as there was a nested h2 and a tag what did not work.